# Angular UI Grid filter will be already filtered by static value

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using Angular ui grid.I am using filter for each column.My requirement is When grid will be loaded then a particular column will be already filtered with a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to set the term in field's filter definition:

> The filter field can be pre-populated by setting filter: { term: 'xxx' } in the column def.

From the docs: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/103_filtering